# Find a subgroup of order $p$ which is not cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ of order $|G| = k$ we may be interested in studying the subgroups of $G.$ If $p < k, p|k$, $p$ prime, the Cauchy theorem assures the existence of a cyclic subgroup of order $p.$ Assuming that $p$ is not prime, and that there is no element of order $p,$ is there any result showing the existence of a subgroup of order $p$ ? Do you know such an example ? Thanks.

Comment: Sylow?  For the maximal power of $p$ dividing the group's order.   It/they may or may not be cyclic.

Comment: No, there is no such result since it is false in general.

Comment: Title: it is better not to use $p$, since $p$ usually denotes a prime number. If $p$ is prime, we cannot find a group of order $p$ which is not cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want,  but $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_3$, for instance,  has a subgroup of order $4$ which isn't cyclic.

Comment: Thanks. How do we see or observe that such a subgroup exists ? Can you give it explicitly ?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Actually,  since finite abelian groups are products of cyclic groups,  which have subgroups of every order,  they have subgroups of every possible order.   They're called CLT.  The subgroup of order $4$ is here isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$, Klein's four group,  which isn't cyclic. An abelian group isn't cyclic precisely when it contains a copy of $\Bbb Z_p×\Bbb Z_p$, for some $p$.  Explicitly here it's $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2×\{e\}$.

Comment: @Shaun I figured I would get such a note (from you or Bill).  But you guys don't own the site.

Comment: For a non-abelian example,  how bout $S_{n-1}\le S_n$.  For $n\gt3$ it isn't cyclic.